# Softmax derivative implementation

Tags: machine-learning, softmax

I know there are already multiple similar questions out there, but still don't really understand the derivative of the softmax function. That's how I implemented the softmax function in java:

```java
public double[] activation(double[] input) {
    double[] exp = new double[input.length];
    double sum = 0;
    for(int neuron = 0; neuron < exp.length; neuron++) {
        exp[neuron] = Math.exp(input[neuron]);
        sum += exp[neuron];
    }

    double[] output = new double[input.length]; 
    for(int neuron = 0; neuron < output.length; neuron++) {
        output[neuron] = exp[neuron] / sum;
    }

    return output;
}
```

And that's what my derivative currently looks like:

```java
public double[] derivative(double[] input) {
    double[] softmax = activation(input);

    double[] output = new double[input.length]; 
    for(int neuron = 0; neuron < output.length; neuron++) {
        output[neuron] = softmax[neuron] * (1d - softmax[neuron]);
    }

    return output;
}
```

I know that there's still something missing in the derivative, as far as I understood it I need to add a case distinction. I often read something about `i==j` or `i!=j`, but I'm not sure what `i` and `j` refer to.

I really hope you can help me with understanding what exactly is missing. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:**
Your `derivative` method isn't implementing the derivative of the softmax function, it's implementing the diagonal of the Jacobian matrix of the softmax function.

**Long answer:**
The softmax function is defined as
$$
\begin{gathered}
\operatorname{softmax} : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n \\
\operatorname{softmax}(\mathbf{x})_i
= \frac{\exp(x_i)}{\sum_{j=1}^n \exp(x_j)},
\end{gathered}
$$
where $\mathbf{x} = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ and $\operatorname{softmax}(\mathbf{x})_i$ is the $i$th component of the vector $\operatorname{softmax}(\mathbf{x})$.
This is what your `activation` method computes.

Your `derivative` method computes the function
$$
\begin{gathered}
\operatorname{derivative} : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n \\
\operatorname{derivative}(\mathbf{x})_i
= \operatorname{softmax}(\mathbf{x})_i (1 - \operatorname{softmax}(\mathbf{x})_i),
\end{gathered}.
$$
This, however, is not the true derivative of the softmax function.

The derivative of $\operatorname{softmax}$ at a vector $\mathbf{x} = (x_1, \ldots, x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is the $n \times n$ Jacobian matrix
$$
D_{\mathbf{x}} \operatorname{softmax}
= \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} \operatorname{softmax}(\mathbf{x})_1
& \cdots &
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_n} \operatorname{softmax}(\mathbf{x})_1 \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} \operatorname{softmax}(\mathbf{x})_n
& \cdots &
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_n} \operatorname{softmax}(\mathbf{x})_n
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
For all $i, j \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$, the quotient rule yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \operatorname{softmax}(\mathbf{x})_i
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \left(\frac{\exp(x_i)}{\sum_{k=1}^n \exp(x_k)}\right) \\
&= \frac{\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \exp(x_i)\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^n \exp(x_k)\right) - \exp(x_i) \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\sum_{k=1}^n \exp(x_k)\right)}{\left(\sum_{k=1}^n \exp(x_k)\right)^2} \\
&= \frac{\delta_{i, j}\exp(x_i)\left(\sum_{k=1}^n \exp(x_k)\right) - \exp(x_i) \exp(x_j)}{\left(\sum_{k=1}^n \exp(x_k)\right)^2}.
\end{aligned}
$$
Here $\delta_{i, j}$ is the Kronecker delta:
$$
\delta_{i, j}
= \begin{cases}
1, & \text{if $i = j$,} \\
0, & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$
Now we have two cases to consider:

- If $i = j$, then $\delta_{i, j} = 1$, so
  $$
  \begin{aligned}
  \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \operatorname{softmax}(\mathbf{x})_i
  &= \frac{\exp(x_i)\left(\sum_{k=1}^n \exp(x_k)\right) - \exp(x_i)^2}{\left(\sum_{k=1}^n \exp(x_k)\right)^2} \\
  &= \frac{\exp(x_i)}{\sum_{k=1}^n \exp(x_k)}
  \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n \exp(x_k) - \exp(x_i)}{\sum_{k=1}^n \exp(x_k)} \\
  &= \frac{\exp(x_i)}{\sum_{k=1}^n \exp(x_k)}
  \left(1 - \frac{\exp(x_i)}{\sum_{k=1}^n \exp(x_k)}\right) \\
  &= \operatorname{softmax}(\mathbf{x})_i (1 - \operatorname{softmax}(\mathbf{x})_i).
  \end{aligned}
  $$
- If $i \neq j$, then $\delta_{i, j} = 0$, so
  $$
  \begin{aligned}
  \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \operatorname{softmax}(\mathbf{x})_i
  &= -\frac{\exp(x_i) \exp(x_j)}{\left(\sum_{k=1}^n \exp(x_k)\right)^2} \\
  &= -\frac{\exp(x_i)}{\sum_{k=1}^n \exp(x_k)} \frac{\exp(x_j)}{\sum_{k=1}^n \exp(x_k)} \\
  &= -\operatorname{softmax}(\mathbf{x})_i \operatorname{softmax}(\mathbf{x})_j.
  \end{aligned}
  $$

Both cases can be consolidated into one by writing
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \operatorname{softmax}(\mathbf{x})_i
= \operatorname{softmax}(\mathbf{x})_i (\delta_{i, j} - \operatorname{softmax}(\mathbf{x})_j)
$$

---

To summarize, the derivative of the softmax function is a matrix, not a vector.

In the case of simpler activations (like sigmoid), the $i$th component of the output only depends on the $i$th component of the input.
Such activations are sometimes called *component-wise* or *element-wise*.
With such activations, the Jacobian matrix is zero off its diagonal, so it is often sufficient (e.g., for backpropagation) to only compute the diagonal.

In the case of the softmax activation, each component of the output depends on each input (if one input component changes, then *all* output components change). This dependence between components makes the Jacobian matrix more complicated, and you can't simply ignore the off-diagonal entries when computing the derivative.

---

**Edit.**
Here is some pseudocode for computing the softmax Jacobian:

**Method** $\operatorname{softmax\_jacobian}(\mathbf{x})$**.**

1. Let $n \leftarrow \operatorname{length}(\mathbf{x})$.
2. Let $\mathbf{p} \leftarrow \operatorname{softmax}(\mathbf{x})$.
3. Initialize $n \times n$ array $\mathbf{output}$.
4. For $i \in \{0, \ldots, n - 1\}$ and $j \in \{0, \ldots, n - 1\}$, let 
   $$\mathbf{output}[i, j] \leftarrow \mathbf{p}[i] * (\delta_{i, j} - \mathbf{p}[j]).$$
   (*Note:* In many languages, $\delta_{i, j}$ is computed as simply `i == j`.)
5. Return $\mathbf{output}$.

Comment: Thank you, that was actually the most helpful explanation I’ve seen. But still, could you explain what exactly i and j refer to or maybe how this could look in (pseudo) code? I’m sorry, but the math goes over my head, I still go to school and never really worked with matrices. Also please excuse my English, it’s not my native language :)

Comment: @Jannik $i$ and $j$ are indices of the components of the input and output. Please see the edit for some pseudocode, I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, that helped me a lot. So the derivatives of each neuron are different, depending on which weight I'm trying to train (I'm using backpropagation)?

Comment: @Jannik the activation of each softmax'ed neuron depends on every other neuron in that layer, so all the neurons contribute to the total derivative at any given neuron

Comment: Okay, I guess I'll have to edit quite a bit of my code, but at least I know why the learning algorithm wasn't working when I used the softmax. Thank you, you really helped me a lot!